# MSSQL Database Search, Identify a Person through Relations

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have tables with property ownership records of people, people personal information, their residence city only, their family number. family numbers are also multiple, one family number from father family, second may be from mother family etc.
A person can get property from his father or mother through inheritance. As well through inheritance or gift from his grand parents or he may buy his own. 
Some of limitations are 
data is not standardized and person name comes up with variations 
for example
Alex full name is Alex Ford
his father name is Henry ford and 
Mother name for example Jessica Alba
Now ownership records could have different entries some of them could have 
where Alex is written with relationship of his father Henry, First name Alex and last name Henry.
At other place it is written with full name "Alex ford" and last name Henry Ford and some other places it is written like Alex  last name Jessica.
Property owner name is written in the form which represent from where he is getting that property, In case inheriting from mother then her mother name is written in his last name.

Problem becomes worst when there exist exact duplicate names with same father name, person could be identified by traversing back in family tree and checking mother name or grand parent names

How could i could find approximate match of person in MS SQL 2008 R2. or how this could it be approached?

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service, you need to have *at least* tried something yourself...

Comment: Your dot key seems to be broken... Structuring your text using sentences would help quite a lot. As it is, your question is illegible.

Comment: hagello apologies for my poor English. Joe Iddon , I am not looking for code asking for suggestion from experts if they can help me please.